# Хочу преобразовать тип данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

```
a = int(input("Введите число: "))  
str(a)
print(len(a))
```

Так как команда len работает только с string я хочу перевести переменную a в string, что-бы он мне вернул количество цифр. Но он мне выдаёт ошибку. Пожалуйста помогите, как правильно преобразовать?

Comment: `print(len(str(a)))` - `str(a)` возвращает новый стринг, т.е. надо сохранить его: `a = str(a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете переделать данные в string и получить количество символов:

```py
a = int(input("Введите число: "))
answer = str(a)

print(len(answer))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Не преобразовывайте input в int, input получает данные в str.

```
a = input("Введите число: ")
print(len(answer))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, почему я сразу не догадался до этого)